# Edit question shows white page with error message

Tags: discussion, bug

I was just trying to edit and found below page

[image]

This is URL where It shows above screen. **https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2418/edit**

Is this bug or this page behaves like this  ?

Thanks.

Comment: works for me now.

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3598472/c7090acbd5d7d7d7a9bf913a7193d347
please use this link then you will see blank screen

Comment: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2418/edit >> is this page working for you ? @Marius

Comment: yes, it does. Maybe there is something wrong with your browser. Try a different one.

Comment: @Marius I tried in another browser as well. 
May be page is working for you because you have access rights for moderator ?

Comment: This can happen for different reasons ... please read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121279/non-user-friendly-message-when-trying-to-edit-post-with-pending-suggested-editio